# AJAX-запрос для формы регистрации

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

Stack технологий - Nodejs, EJS, MongoDB, jQuery.

Есть форма регистрации, после нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" необходимо чтобы пользователь был зареган в базе и появлялось модальное окно (к примеру: подтверждение смс-кода). Если есть похожием темы, или где-то почитать - прикрепите ссылки пожалуйста.

EJS-форма регистрации:

```
<form class="needs-validation" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="md-form form-sm df-form-line">
                <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control text-input" name="login" required>
                <label for="login">Логин <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback text-right">
                    Напишите, пожалуйста, логин.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="md-form form-sm df-form-line">
                <!--<input type="password" id="password" class="form-control text-input" required>-->
                <input type="password" class="form-control text-input" name="password" required>
                <label for="password">Пароль <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback text-right">
                    Минимум 8 символов.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="md-form form-sm df-form-line">
                <input type="text" id="surname" class="form-control text-input" name="lastname"
                       required>
                <label for="surname">Фамилия <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback text-right">
                    Напишите, пожалуйста, Вашу фамилию.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="md-form form-sm df-form-line">
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control text-input" name="name"
                       required>
                <label for="name">Имя <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback text-right">
                    Напишите, пожалуйста, Ваше имя.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="md-form form-sm df-form-line">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control text-input">
                <label for="email">Электронная почта</label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback text-right">
                    Укажите Вашу электронную почту.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
            <div class="md-form form-sm df-form-line">
                <input type="text" class="form-control "
                       name="phone" required>
                <!--<label for="phone">Телефон <span class="required">*</span></label>-->
                <div class="invalid-feedback text-right">
                    Укажите Ваш номер телефона.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6  mb-3">
            <div class="mb-1">
                <p class="f-small">Ваш пол</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check mb-1">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sex" id="exampleRadios1"
                       value="false" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                    Женский
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check mb-1">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sex" id="exampleRadios2"
                       value="true">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                    Мужской
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
            <div class="mb-1">
                <p class="f-small">Дата рождения <span class="required">*</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="md-form">
                <input placeholder="Календарь" type="date" name="birthDate"
                       id="date-picker" class="form-control datepicker" required>
                <label for="date-picker"></label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback text-right">
                Укажите дату рождения.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
            <div class="control-group">

                <select id="select-beast" class="demo-default" name="city">
                    <option value="">Город проживания</option>

                    <% city.forEach(function(cities){ %>
                    <option data-values='<%- cities.id %>'>
                        <%= cities.name %>
                    </option>
                    <% }); %>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
            <div class="mb-1">
                <p class="f-small">Вид аккаунта</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-check mb-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="kind"
                               id="searchTrenerRadios" value="Sportsman" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="searchTrenerRadios">
                            Ищу тренера
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-check mb-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="kind"
                               id="trenerRadios" value="Coach">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="trenerRadios">
                            Тренерую
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 tac">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-df btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light btn-registration"
                    value="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#socialModal">Регистрация
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Мой route:

```
router.post('/user/registration', controller.registration);
```

И к нему продолжение:

```
 registration: function (req, res, next) {
    userController.registration(req, res, next, function (err, user) {
        req.user.id = user.id;
        userController.phoneCreate(req,res,next);
    });
},
```

Собственно, хочу сделать аякс-запросом, чтобы когда нажал на кнопку появлялось модальное окно. apiRequest - кастомная(универсальная) функция, которая парсит и формирует наш запрос.

```
$(".btn-registration").click(function () {
    derzyfit.apiRequest({
        url: "/user/registration",
        type: "POST",
        // data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }, function (res) {
        // $(".btn-registration").html(res);
    })
});
```

Подскажите с чего начать, пожалуйста. [Убрал `type="submit"`,и из `form` атрибуты `method` и `action`]

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то это поможет

```
let modal = $('#modal-form')
modal.find('.modal-body').empty().append(data)
modal.find('button.save').off('click').on('click', function () {
let data = modal.find('form').serializeObject()
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/regions',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
  },
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function (result) {
    if (result.status === 'ok') {
      modal.modal('hide')
      $('#directory-regions').trigger('click')
      return
    }
    renderRegionForm(result)
  }
})
})
modal.modal('show')
```